# What are required assemblies for Entity Framework 4.1 and SQL Compact?

Tags: entity-framework-4, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-4.1, nuget, sql-server-ce-4

Previously I used Entity Framework 4.0 CTP5 (code-first) and SQL Compact in my projects. I had the following packages installed using NuGet:

1. SQLCE.4.0.8435.1 (version 4.0.8435.1)
2. [EFCodeFirst 0.8](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/EFCodeFirst) (version 4.0.30319.0)
3. [EFCodeFirst.SqlServerCompact.0.8](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/EFCodeFirst.SqlServerCompact) (version 4.0.8435.1)

Now when [EF 4.1 RC is published](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-release-candidate-available.aspx), I want to update all my libraries to the latest version. NuGet feed doesn't contain any updates for SQLCE.4.0.8435.1 anymore, but it has a new package '[SqlServerCompact - 4.0.8482.1](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/SqlServerCompact)' (new package, not a new version of existing package). Presume, that it was just renamed and I should install it. Is it right? Presume, yes.

NuGet also doesn't contain any updates for 'EFCodeFirst' and 'EFCodeFirst.SqlServerCompact' packages. But it has a new '[EntityFramework 4.1.10311.0](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/EntityFramework)' package.

So what should I install? Are '[EntityFramework 4.1.10311.0](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/EntityFramework)' and '[SqlServerCompact - 4.0.8482.1](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/SqlServerCompact)' enough for using EF code first with SQL Compact?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, we're working on an EntityFramework and EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact this week.

Comment: Scott, does that mean you are working on the nuget packages with those names? Also - can you please confirm or deny this statement from the original question 

"Are 'EntityFramework 4.1.10311.0' and 'SqlServerCompact - 4.0.8482.1' enough for using EF code first with SQL Compact?"

Thanks

Comment: Yes, we are working on EntityFramework and EntityFrameworm.SqlServerCompact today...actually looks like it's up now? http://nuget.org/List/Packages/EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact

Comment: Thanks Scott - just tried it out and everything worked great

From the console ran

Comment: From Package Manager Console ran

PM> Install-Package EntityFramework
then
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact

Side Note: my project is a WPF app and it was complaining about Webactivator, which wants System.web and that is not part of the .NET 4.0 Client Profile, so I just switched the profile to the full .NET 4.0 one.

Comment: Scott, thanks! Everything works fine with new 'EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact'

Comment: So if EFCodeFirst.SqlServerCompact is now legacy, is there any way to update the description as Microsoft did for the jQuery vsdoc package - http://nuget.org/List/Packages/jQuery.vsdoc ?

Comment: @Nick If you'd still like to use the .NET 4 Client Profile, you can also simply comment out the "WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod" line in **App_Start/EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact.cs**.

//[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(Typecast.App_Start.EntityFramework_SqlServerCompact), "Start")]

Answer (score 0):

I think we have to wait for them to release an updated EF + SQL CE library /sign